# How can I make a button in Javascript that takes char responses and act accordingly to them?

Tags: javascript, button, char, font-size

For instance, the button it clicked, the prompt comes up and asks the user: small medium or large (s/m/l)/. depending on your response, it will make the

font size 75%, 100% or 150%. If you instead say y or n or 23, it will tell you that that isn't a correct response and ask you again.

Also, how would you go about changing the font size like this?

Comment: I wouldn't give the option of input as you open yourself to sql injections or whatever. Since you limit it to s/m/l I would provide checkboxen.

Comment: I cannot do that, the options are user char response, no user will see this, that is not a concern.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the sort of thing you are looking for?

**Edited as per comment below**

```js
function textChange() {

    var text = document.getElementById('inputSize').value;
    var element = document.getElementById('text');
    document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = '';

    if (text == 's') {
        element.className = 'small';
        return;
    }

    if (text == 'm') {
        element.className = 'medium';
        return;
    }

    if (text == 'l') {
        element.className = 'large';
        return;
    }
    
    if (text == '') {
        return;
    }

    document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'This is not a correct response';
}
```

```css
.small {
    font-size: 75%;
}
.medium{
    font-size: 100%;
}
.large {
    font-size: 150%;
}
.error {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="text">
    <p>Text goes here</p>
    <p id="error" class="error"></p>
    <input id="inputSize" type="text" onkeyup="textChange();" />
</div>
```

Comment: yeah that is good, but those are three buttons, it needs a single field that a user can enter a char, where the user can make a mistake. enter s/m/l (x) and it needs to be able to change an existing <p>

Comment: Ok let me give it a go using an input.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below snippet

```js
function testFunction()
{
var x = prompt("Enter a character");
if(x == "s") size="50%";
if(x == "m") size="75%";
if(x == "l") size="100%";
document.getElementById("pId").style.fontSize = size;
}
```

```html
<p id="pid">A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p>
<input type=button onclick="testFunction()" value="Click me">
```